# Error while starting SharePoint 2013 Content Enrichment Web Service

Tags: cews

1)  In our application, there are multiple content source, fetching data from different sources, most of the content source are using SIT Search Index connector

2)  These connector are configured to get data from multiple Stored procedures these settings are mentioned in the an xml file mapped in the SIT Search Index connector.

3)  The content Source are utilized to display data in the SharePoint Portal through content search web parts.

4)  These content Sources have stopped working and when gone through the crawl log, a common  error was displayed “The item failed due to an error occurring when sending or receiving data to the external content processing enrichment web service”

5)  On investigating in the ULS logs a recurring error was mentioned as below

[Microsoft.CrawlerFlow-adcabbb9-7508-4da4-b965-882d3effa84e] Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionHelper : Evaluation failure detected:    Operator          : ContentEnrichment    Operator type     : ContentEnrichmentClient    Error id          : 3206    Correlation id    : 29eb7471-82e8-44fd-aa16-891be4bc5885    Partition id      : 0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b    Message           : Failed to send the item to the content processing enrichment service.    49691C90-7E17-101A-A91C-08002B2ECDA9:#9: https://localhost:443/my/host/Person.aspx?accountname=TCAD%5Cingadm    id                : ssic://281102  System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation   (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.IO.IOException: The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation

6)  The description says “The requested operation could not be loaded due to limitation of file system”, and pointing to “ContentEnrichment’

7)  The event logs of the server also logged error related to the SharePoint2013ContentEnrichmentWebService with description “The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation”

8)  For troubleshooting we checked the following
a.  The disk space on the server and it was around 130gb free
b.  We checked whether SharePoint2013ContentEnrichmentWebService is working or not and it was in Started mode.
c.  We tried to restart it and it started and stopped immediately with the below error
[image: Error]

d.  We tried to reset IIS server and machine reboot but it didn’t worked, the service remained in Stop mode.
e.  We also tried increasing, the limit of the search service response by changing in the “web.config” file present in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\SearchService  by changing values of attributes like maxArrayLength="2147483647" and then tried restarting SharePoint2013ContentEnrichmentWebService but it didn’t start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot your issue as following:

1.Change the maxReceivedMessageSize = "8388608" in web.config file.

2.Restart the CEWS windows service on all servers using PowerShell command:

```
//restart Windows Services
$servers = @("server1","server2")
$services = @("SharePoint2013ContentEnrichmentWebService")

foreach($service in $services)
{ 
    foreach($server in $servers)
    {
     $sc = sc.exe "\\$server" query $service
      if($sc[3].Contains("RUNNING"))
        {
            "Stopping service $service on server $server"
         $t = sc.exe "\\$server" stop $service
            sleep 1
        }
        else
        {
            "Service $service is already stopped on server $server"     
        }
    }

    foreach($s in $servers)
    {
     $sc = sc.exe "\\$server" query $service
      if($sc[3].Contains("STOPPED"))
        {
            "Starting service $service on server $server"
         $t = sc.exe "\\$server" start $service
            sleep 1
        }
        else
        {
            "Service $service is already started or starting on server $server"
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Search Runbook – CEWS Pipeline Toolkit](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onsearch/2016/03/25/sharepoint-search-runbook-cews-pipeline-toolkit/)